# Pretrained model for deep_speech2 tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found an implementation of the DeepSpeech2 model here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deep_speech#deepspeech2-model

This implementation has only to train and evaluate and no pre-trained models available. So I trained the model with a minimal dataset myself and tried to run inference but I didn't get meaningful results. So here my question is

1. Does this implementation work well if I train with a large amount of dataset?
2. Is there a pre-trained model available for this?

Thanks in advance